# ArcGIS Toolbox Tools visible in Pro, not in Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool

I created these tools in desktop years ago and they worked up until yesterday and then they just disappeared in desktop? I can see them in Pro, but not desktop? Any reasons as to why this happened? I made no changes to the tools, but I do believe I viewed them in Pro at one point.

**ArcCatalog**: [image]

**ArcGIS Pro**: [image]

Comment: Did you use the script tools in a higher version of ArcMap or in ArcGIS Pro? I've found the same thing happen to me after trying to use it in a higher version, as if the software automatically converts the tool to the latest version you use it in.

Comment: Jacob's comment is the answer -- You've almost certainly done some sort of update or save from Pro, making the toolbox not compatible with ArcMap. Hopefully you have a copy of these tools somewhere else.

Comment: @JacobHelfman you should add this as the answer. I did roll back to a previous version from our off site backups, so I am backup and operational. As an FYI, all I did was open the tool properties in ArcGIS Pro and wabam, Desktop compatibility lost. Hence why I have been trying to keep Pro and Desktop tools separate (that and Python 2x to 3x Issues). 

There should be some sort of warning or ability to lock a toolbox to a specific version, not just automatic updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom tool, model or script in a newer version of ArcGIS automatically converts it to the newer version. For example, using a script tool in ArcGIS Pro would remove the tool’s backward compatibility with ArcMap or an earlier version of ArcGIS Desktop. A previous thread discusses potential workarounds for this (in case you didn’t make a backup), and focuses on the actual toolbox: [Opening ArcToolbox Tools in previous versions of ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258943/opening-arctoolbox-tools-in-previous-versions-of-arcmap).